# How can I express the integral path of a curve integral?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, regions

A second sort of curve integral:

$\oint_{\Gamma}\left(y^{2}-z^{2}\right) d x+\left(z^{2}-x^{2}\right) d y+\left(x^{2}-y^{2}\right) d z$

The integral path $\Gamma$ is the cut-off line obtained by cutting the surface of the cube($\{(x, y, z) \mid 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1,0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1,0 \leqslant z \leqslant 1\}$) with a plane ($x+y+z=\frac{3}{2}$). If you look from the forward direction of the ox axis, take the counterclockwise direction.

You can find the integration path in this 3D graph. It is the boundary of the hexagon, and the direction is counterclockwise:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ContourPlot3D[{x + y + z == 3/2, x == 0, x == 1, y == 0, z == 0,
    y == 1, z == 1}, {x, #, #2}, {y, #3, #4}, {z, #5, #6}, Mesh -> 1,
   ImageSize -> 500, ViewPoint -> {5, 1, 2},
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[{x, y,
      z}, \!\(TraditionalForm\`\(-0.1\) ⩽
          x ⩽ 1.1 && \(-0.1\) ⩽
          y ⩽ 1.1 && \(-0.1\) ⩽
          z ⩽ 1.1\) && x + y + z <= 1.6],
   ContourStyle -> (Directive @@@ {{Red, Opacity@.7}, {Green,
        Opacity@.7}, {Blue, Opacity@.7}, {Yellow, Opacity@.7}, {Cyan,
        Opacity@.7}, {Gray, Opacity@.7}, {Pink, Opacity@.7}}),
   Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
   PlotPoints -> 50] & @@@ {{-1, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2}}
```

I tried to write the code of integral path, but `RegionBoundary` returns the original plane region as the boundary.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
plane = ImplicitRegion[
  x + y + z == 1.5 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1, {x,
   y, z}];
line = RegionBoundary[plane]
```

> ```
> ImplicitRegion[x+y+z\[Equal]1.5&&0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&0<=z<=1,{x,y,z}]
> ```

Comment: 1. "it doesn't work" and "Failed" are vague, better to replace them with more specific description like "it returns unevaluated", "it returns an incorrect result", "it causes the warning....", etc. 2. I don't think `ImplicitRegion` is the right way to go, because even if it _works_, the direction needed for calculating the integral is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible work-around:

```
poly = Cube[1/2 {1, 1, 1}, 1] // RegionBoundary

lines = Line@poly[[1]][[#]] & /@ poly[[2]]

pts={x, y, z} /. 
    Solve @@ RegionIntersection[#, ImplicitRegion[x + y + z == 3/2, {x, y, z}]] &@
  RegionConvert[#, "Implicit"] & /@ lines // Flatten[#, 1] & // DeleteDuplicates
(* {{1/2, 1, 0}, {1, 1/2, 0}, {1, 0, 1/2}, 
    {1/2, 0, 1}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1, 1/2}} *)
```

At this point, the order of `pts` happens to be desired:

```
Arrow@Append[pts, pts[[1]]] // Graphics3D
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But using `FindCurvePath` should make the solution a bit more general:

```
ptsordered = pts[[First@FindCurvePath@pts]];

ListLinePlot3D@ptsordered /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
poly = RegionIntersection[Hyperplane[{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 3/2}], Cuboid[]]
```

> Polygon[{{1, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1}, {0, 1/2, 1}, {0, 1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1,
> 0}, {1, 1/2, 0}}]

or

```
reg=ImplicitRegion[x+y+z==3/2&&0<=x<=1&&0<=y<=1&&0<=z<=1,{x,y,z}];
poly=MeshPrimitives[Region`Mesh`MergeCells[DiscretizeRegion[reg]],2][[1]]
```

> Polygon[{{1., 0.5, 0.}, {1., 0., 0.5}, {0.49999999999999994, 0., 1.}, {0., 0.49999999999999994,
> 1.}, {0., 1., 0.5}, {0.49999999999999994, 1., 0.}}]

```
paraEq={Abs[t-1]+3/2 Abs[t-1/2]+3/2 Abs[t-1/3]-3/2 Abs[t-5/6]-Abs[t]/2,3/2 Abs[t-1]-3/2 Abs[t-1/2]-3/2 Abs[t-2/3]+3/2 Abs[t-1/6],-Abs[t-1]+2 Abs[t]-3/2 Abs[t-1/3]+3/2 Abs[t-2/3]-3/2 Abs[t-1/6]+3/2 Abs[t-5/6]};

paraEq2={Sqrt[3]/2  Cos[θ] Sec[1/6 ArcCos[-Cos[6 θ]]],Sqrt[3]/2  Sec[1/6 ArcCos[-Cos[6 θ]]] Sin[θ],1}.{{0,-(1/2),1/2},{-(1/Sqrt[3]),1/(2 Sqrt[3]),1/(2 Sqrt[3])},{1/2,1/2,1/2}};

Show[Graphics3D[poly],
ParametricPlot3D[paraEq,{t,0,1}],
ParametricPlot3D[paraEq2,{θ,0,2Pi}]]
```

> 

[image]

```
rule=Thread[{x,y,z}->paraEq];
Integrate[Hold[D[{x,y,z},t].{y^2-z^2,z^2-x^2,x^2-y^2}]/.rule/.Abs->RealAbs//ReleaseHold,{t,1,0}]
```

> $-\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you so much!